# Can't query Twitter API v2 with elevated acces project/app

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trting to query Twitter API v2 with elevated research access via tweepy, but it still gives me a `403 Forbidden`.
[image: evelevated acces proof of my app]

```py
client = tweepy.Client(
    bearer_token=BEARER_TOKEN,
#    consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY,
#    consumer_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET,
#    access_token=OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN,
#    access_token_secret=OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
    
)

test = client.search_all_tweets(query="#something",
                                start_time = "2023-01-01")
print(test)
```

Response:

> Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
> When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.

I've tried all the combinations of the commented lines when created the client, nothing works.

What am I doing wrong?

No problem with normal access endpoints and `bearer_token` param. However, can't **nothing** when using consumer_key/secret and acces_token(_secret) instead. Maybe this is the real issue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This table](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#item0) shows which account access or not

If you has free account (Essential or Elevated), you can't use `search_all_tweets` method. It is equivalent the [`GET /2/tweets/search/all`](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/api-reference/get-tweets-search-all) API.

[image]

You can check which account has in your `Developer Portal`

```
https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/products
```

In the three tabs (Essential, Elevated, and Academic Research),
Checked green item is your account.
[image]

But you can use recent 7 days search API by `search_recent_tweets()` even if free account.

That is equivalent with  [`GET /2/tweets/search/recent`](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/api-reference/get-tweets-search-recent)

Comment: ahh, you're right I missunderstood elevated access with research access. So focused in making work. Thank you for the enlightment

Comment: No problem, I am also elevated account user.