# Problem with keys and tokens when making requests to Postman via the Twitter API v2 collection

Tags: postman, twitter-oauth, twitter-api-v2

For information, I have a Free account.

I want to make requests on Postman with the Twitter API V2 collection to test the API and verify that everything works (keys and tokens) before developing an application.

I try to make the GET Single Tweet request (Tweet Lookup) and this is what I get as an error:

```
{
    "client_id": "26990924",
    "detail": "When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.",
    "registration_url": "https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/projects/overview",
    "title": "Client Forbidden",
    "required_enrollment": "Appropriate Level of API Access",
    "reason": "client-not-enrolled",
    "type": "https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/client-forbidden"
}
```

I’ve looked all over the forums and I think I’m one of the unlucky ones who have keys and tokens that are not valid.

The authorization is with the bearer token and my environment is OK.

Thanks in advance!

(I tried to regenerate tokens and keys a lot of times and it doesn't work)

Answer (score 4):

Musk made twitter api paid.

Free access only to 3 endpoints:
`POST /2/tweets`,
`DELETE /2/tweets/:id` and `GET /2/users/me`

source: https://developer.twitter.com/en

TL;DR Musk wants $100 for api that get tweets with rate limit 15 requests / 15 minute
[image]